# How to use the tilde selector with (this) jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Good afternoon all, I'm trying to select a specific sibling within a div.  I've tried using many different recommendations I found and can't seem to get any to work.  Using [this](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/), it looks like I might be able to use something like this:

```
$( "#prev ~ div" ).css( "border", "3px groove blue" );
```

However, I would like to use (this) within the selector, maybe like so:

```
&(this " ~ p").show();
```

Basically, I'm just trying to show a paragraph sibling when a certain event is triggered.  If anyone has a better way, I'm more than happy to accept suggestions.  I've tried other ways such as using next() and siblings("p") but can't seem to get it to work.  Here is a portion of the html and jquery I currently have.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 items">
    <div class="item">
        <h6>Dynamic Web Programming<h6>
        <img src="DynamicWebProgramming.jpg">
        <p>This book is a great tool for learning to develop Dynamic Web Pages.</p>  
         // This is the paragraph that is hidden and I want to show on mouseover
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item p").hide();

    $(".item h6").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("mouseover");
        $(this).siblings().addClass("mouseover");
        $(this).siblings("p").show(); // This is where I want to call .show() for the 
                                         specific sibling
    })

    $(".item p").click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("mouseover");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("mouseover");
    })
})
```

If anyone can offer any suggestions, that would be great!
Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, I'd change mouseover to hover:

```
$(".item h6").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("mouseover");
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass("mouseover");
    $(this).siblings("p").show(); // This is where I want to call .show() for the  specific sibling
},function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("mouseover");
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass("mouseover");
    $(this).siblings("p").hide();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/q31xLtk3/) here

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot!  Do you mind me asking why the $(this).siblings("p").show() doesn't work with mouseover?  The reason I ask is because I didn't want the paragraph to hide again when no longer hovering.  I was able to achieve this by removing the .hide() from the handlerOut funtion, but I don'e understand why it wouldn't work in the mouseover.  Thanks again!

Comment: It seemed to work with me, I thought you wanted to toggle it though. Here it is working with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/0qc1muw4/

Comment: @AndyGiebel **hover** uses **mouseenter** instead of **mouseover**. http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: Yea even more weird, I was able to get it to work with fiddle, but when I moved it to my js file, it still isn't working!  Also, I do want it to toggle, but only on click.  (I know it seems weird, but it's for learning purposes :D)

Comment: Hmm thanks a lot for your help, but do you have any idea why I can get it working on jsfiddle but not locally?  I'm using jquery 1.11.3 (jsfiddle worked with 1.11.0).  I know the hover and mouseover is working fine because it adds the mouseover class as it should.  For some reason it still just doesn't like the $(this).siblings("p").show();  Thanks again

Comment: There isn't :( doing some more messing around, this is just so odd.  I removed the hide() so that it's never hidden to test the click.  This successfully hid the paragraph.  So in the mouseover event, since it's shown I tried using the example that works on w3 shools : $(this).siblings("p").css({"color": "red", "border-color": "red"}); which also isn't working.  It's like for some reason in that one function it doesn't think that paragraph is a sibling?

Comment: To add to my last comment, they definitely are siblings since the "mouseover" class is toggled for the paragraph sibling.